# GitHub GraphQL: Get all forks of specific repository

Tags: github, graphql, fork

I would like to get a list of all the forks of a specific repository.

When I try the following on [explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/)

```graphql
  repository( owner: "someOrg", name: "specificRepo"){
        name
        forkCount
        forks(first: 12){
          totalCount
          nodes{
            name
          }
        }
  }
}
```

It returns the fork count correctly, but inside nodes, the name is just the original repo name. But I would like it to give the names of all the forked repositories.

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "name": "specificRepo",
      "forkCount": 12,
      "forks": {
        "totalCount": 1,
        "nodes": [
          {
            "name": "specificRepo",
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _name_? The repository name doesn't change, is `nameWithOwner` what you're looking for?

Comment: name of the forks

Comment: in case someone forks a repo, and then chanages the name of their fork

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fork a repo and then change the name, the `name` field will reflect the changed name, not the original name. For example, here's a fork of `Semantic-UI`:

```graphql
{
  repository(
    owner: "Semantic-Org"
    name: "Semantic-Ui"
  ) {
    name
    forkCount
    forks(
      first: 12
      orderBy: { field: NAME, direction: DESC }
    ) {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "name": "Semantic-UI",
      "forkCount": 4936,
      "forks": {
        "totalCount": 4743,
        "nodes": [
          {
            "name": "WEB_JS_GUI-Semantic-UI"
          },
          {
            "name": "Vanz-Sing-In"
          },
          {
            "name": "Somewhat-Semantic-UI"
          },
          {
            "name": "semantic_1.0_experiment"
          },
          {
            "name": "semanticui"
          },
          {
            "name": "semantic.ui_main"
          },
          {
            "name": "Semantic-UI-V2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Semantic-UI-tr"
          },
          {
            "name": "Semantic-UI-tr"
          },
          {
            "name": "Semantic-UI-Stylus"
          },
          {
            "name": "Semantic-UI-pt-br"
          },
          {
            "name": "Semantic-UI-pp"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm - because this is a github graphql question, could you provide the graph ql solution?

Comment: @maddie Updated answer with example

Comment: The solution I'm looking for would answer the title of the post, how to get all the forks of a specific repository. Do you know how to change my query so that I could list all the forks of a repository (access the name of the fork, and owner of the fork). I can do this with a curl command: `curl GET https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/forks`

Comment: If you're asking how to bypass the limit, you can't. You can only fetch 100 nodes at a time. So outside having to paginate through the results, your original query is fine.

Comment: But my original query doesn't get the names of the forks, it just returns the name of the orig repository - I'd like to see the names of all 12 forks. This is useful for forks that have been changed to a name different than the orig repo

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that -- like I said, the `name` field in your query returns the name of the fork, not the name of the original repo.

Comment: You can run the query in your question against the `Semantic-Ui` repo, sorting the forks in descending order by name -- you'll see the first handful of forks with names different from the original repo.

Comment: How would I sort them by name?

Answer (score 0):

Today you can request to add the `nameWithOwner` field as well and even the `url`. That will give you the information you need.

```graphql
{
  repository(
    owner: "Semantic-Org"
    name: "Semantic-Ui"
  ) {
    name
    forkCount
    forks(
      first: 12
      orderBy: { field: NAME, direction: DESC }
    ) {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        name
        nameWithOwner
        url
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which will give you:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "name": "Semantic-UI",
      "forkCount": 5133,
      "forks": {
        "totalCount": 4919,
        "nodes": [
          {
            "name": "Vanz-Sing-In",
            "nameWithOwner": "semantic-apps/Vanz-Sing-In",
            "url": "https://github.com/semantic-apps/Vanz-Sing-In"
          },

          etc.

        }
    }
  }
}
```